# What is the difference between #include and copy & paste?

Tags: c++, c++-cli, c-preprocessor

I have a macro definition for template instantiations that looks approximately like this:

```
#define INSTANTIATE_TEMPLATE(typeName) \
  template FooBarImpl<C##typeName>;
```

So it doesn't really do much.
Next I have a ton of calls to this macro.

```
INSTANTIATE_TEMPLATE(OneType)
INSTANTIATE_TEMPLATE(AnotherType)
INSTANTIATE_TEMPLATE(TypeThree)
```

and so forth...
This seems to work fine. I just tried to create an include for the instantiations that only contained those last lines and replaced the lines with

```
#include "instantiations.hpp"
```

However, this new version does not compile. It seems that all the includes at the top of the file are invisible when the templates are being instantiated.

Quoting the [MS docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4.aspx):

> The #include directive tells the preprocessor to treat the contents of a specified file as if those contents had appeared in the source program at the point where the directive appears.

So I assume this is some sort of ordering issue with the way #includes and macros are evaluated by the preprocessor. But how does it really work and what is going on?

Comment: I also tried completely removing the macro and putting the template FooBarImpl<COneType>; ... definitions in a file and #include that. Same error so probably NOT an ordering issue.

Comment: Can you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: answer: no differences

Comment: It's a huge project so I'm not sure cutting it down to a minimal example is feasible.

Comment: Then you can go about it the other way round - start from scratch and add things until you arrive at the bad behaviour. Because just from what you've told us, it should work fine.

Comment: Did you put the `#include "instantiations.hpp"` at the same point in the cpp file where the original `INSTANTIATE_TEMPLATE` calls were?

Comment: @DavidYaw Yes, I did.

Comment: You'll have to show us exactly what your code looks like and the error messages. There's a disconnect in what your providing us.

Comment: Answering the question in the title: One difference is the behavior of relative path includes. In each case, includes are relative to the location of the file. If you copy and paste, you might be changing the location of the code and thereby break included includes or actually include files of the same name but on a different path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is embarassing.

The problem was that I had the name of the include wrong. There are two files that have almost the same name and I autocompleted to the wrong name and never noticed. The names are really poorly chosen (I did not know the other existed) and only differ in "...Attribute..." vs. "...Attr...".

I'm not really sure what to take away from this. Maybe I should use the "open document" shortcut instead of clicking on the open tab.

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 Okay.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include it after defining `INSTANTIATE_TEMPLATE`.

Comment: What are the exact errors you're getting? It seems to work just fine for me.

Comment: C2039, C2146, C4430, C2602, C2868, ... it basically looks like some includes are missing. It's a huge project so I'm not sure cutting it down to a minimal example is feasible.

Answer (score 0):

I think Visual Studio is trying to compile the .hpp file as if it were a .cpp file. When compiled by itself, it doesn't have the #includes that are before it when #included from another file.

Pull up the properties for the .hpp, and make sure that under Configuration Properties -> General, it lists the Item Type as "C/C++ header".

Comment: It does list the item type as C/C++ header.